# why we should use docker for .Net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

My Question is why should we use Docker with .Net core according to Microsoft .Net core is platform independent framework so we can host .net core app on any platform. Please guide me about that it is really confusing.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Who says you should?

Comment: _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Docker image has a dotnet image layer which is a layer on top of a normal linux image. Why would you use this one instead of the Linux image?

### Ease of use

You can use the dotnet build/publish output on any system that has the dotnet core runtime, such as Linux, Windows or Mac. This means that you can test the same code that runs anywhere. If you didn't do that, you would have have to build your .net app for every platform you target.

### Reduce build/copy time

If you build for any specific platform, then every time you build it will copy all the dlls and files needed for that environment: so all system.dlls and .po files for a Linux environment.

This means more stuff to copy to the bin folder every time. This makes it slower to build and startup the application.